# count the number of split points

Tags: algorithm, split

I just got a question about counting the split points in a integer array, to ensure there is at least one duplicated integer on the two sides.

ex:

```
1 1 4 2 4 2 4 1
```

we can either split it into:

```
1 1 4 2 | 4 2 4 1
```

or

```
1 1 4 2 4 | 2 4 1
```

so that there is at least one '1', '2' ,and '4' are in both sides.

The integer can range from 1 to 100,000

The complexity requires O(n). How to solve this question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make one pass over the array and build `count[i] = how many times the value i appears in the array`. The problem is only solvable if `count[i] >= 2` for all non-zero values. You can use this array to tell how many distinct values you have in your array.

Next, make another pass and using another array `count2[i]` (or you can reuse the first one), keep track of when you have visited each value at least once. Then use that position as your split point.

**Example:**

```
1 1 4 2 4 2 4 1
count = [3, 2, 0, 4] => 3 distinct values

1 1 4 2 4 2 4 1
^ => 1 distinct value so far
  ^ => 1 distinct value so far
    ^ => 2 distinct values so far
      ^ => 3 distinct values so far => this is your split point
```

There might be cases for which there is no solution, for example if the last `1` was at the beginning as well. To detect this, you can just make another pass over the rest of the array after you have decided on the split point and see if you still have all the values on that side.

You can avoid this last pass by using the `count` and `count2` arrays to detect when you can no longer have a split point. This is left as an exercise.

Comment: @G.Bach - it can, but my explanation deals with just the first split point. To enumerate them all, the same method applies, but you must be a little more careful about how you decide on a split point (how you ensure that you have enough of each value available on each side).

Comment: If you enumerate, you'll get Ω(n^2) in the worst case since there may be Ω(n) split points, no?

Comment: @G.Bach - no, you can still keep it `O(n)`. Think about how you can use the `count` and `count2` arrays to get rid of the loop I mention in the end.